# Reducibility of Cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be the cyclic group $C_{4}$ and consider the 2-dimensional representations of G. Why does extending scalars to the complex numbers let this representation become reducible? I understand how it is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ by don't see how it is reducible for $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Can you describe the $2$-dimensional real reps of $G$?

Comment: in the real case, wouldn't it just be multiplication by i, where we consider the cyclic group

Comment: (You should make explicit ove what field your representation is defined, by the way)

Comment: I meant if we define G as the set 1, i, -1, -i, and we have the representation a+bi, where a and b are reals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $G$ is finite and abelian, its irreducible complex representations are all of dimension $1$. As your representation is of dimension $2$ and as dimension does not change when you extend scalars to $\mathbb C$, the resulting representation cannot be irreducible!

Comment: how exactly would the components look like for the case where we have the representation $a+bi$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and G acts as multiplication by i? clearly it's irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ but I'm not sure how the components look like over $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: I tried using the basis elements, $1$ and $i$, as the components, but I realized that the extension $V \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ where the scalars go to $\mathbb{C}$ seem to make the original representation look like $\mathbb{C}$ itself. So if I take a, then the subspace spanned by it would just be complex numbers times a, which would just be the original space